# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{2}$ where $a_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-a_n}$

Tags: calculus

I have the following question:

For arbitrary $a_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $0<a_0<1$,  $a_{n+1}:=1-\sqrt{1-a_n}$ and $a_n$ is a real sequence.

I want to show that:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{2}$

I have proved that the

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$

I do not know how to continue. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{a_{n+1}\left(1+\sqrt{1-a_n}\right)}{a_n\left(1+\sqrt{1-a_n}\right)} =\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-a_n}}.$$

Comment: I thought about using $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$

Comment: But than there is the a_n left in the numerator. How do you get the 1 and this denominator? But the hint is clear I think, because now follows $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-a_n}}=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-0}}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Oh, I am so stupid.... a_n cancels itself out... Thanks for your help. That was really fast. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to estimate
$\lim_n\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ provided that one has shown that $a_n\rightarrow0$ when $0<a_0<1$:

$$a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$$

where $f(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x}$. Then

\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{f(a_n)}{a_n}=\frac{f(a_n)-f(0)}{a_n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f'(0)=\frac12
\end{align}

---

For sake of completion, here is a proof that $\lim_na_n=0$.

By induction, $0<a_n<1$.

- For $n=0$ this holds by choice of $a_0$.
- Assume statement holds for some $n\geq0$. Then $0<1-a_n<1$ and so $0<1-\sqrt{1-a_n}=a_{n+1}<1$.

From
$a_{n+1}-a_n=1-a_n-\sqrt{1-a_n}=\sqrt{1-a_n}(\sqrt{1-a_n}-1)=-\frac{a_n\sqrt{1-a_n}}{\sqrt{1-a_n}+1}<0$

it follows that $a_n$ is monotone decreasing and so I it converges. The limit $a$ satisfied $0\leq a<1$ and the fixed point equation
$a=1-\sqrt{1-a}$; hence $a=0$.